# onmouseenter doesn't work for children of button in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

With layout like this:

```
<button><span>foo</span></button>
```

`onmouseenter` on the span never fires in firefox. It does in chrome. For other wrapping elements, it will fire. This, for example,

```
<label><span>foo</span></label>
```

will call `onmouseenter` for the span in firefox. It's only firefox, and only buttons, where I have this problem. The button is outside my control, so I can't put a handler on it, or change the type of element. I can only change the children.

jsfiddle, showing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/gjwp04uk/3/

Answer (score 0):

If, when you say you can't change the button, it's because you *don't have direct access to it*, as in, you can't put an ID on it, you could still add the handlers to it through the children. Change your HTML to this:

```
<!-- Inline style used for simplicity, you should probably put it in a CSS file -->
<button><span id=span style="pointer-events: none">point here: </span></button>

<span id=result></span>
```

and your JS to this:

```
var span = document.getElementById('span');
var res = document.getElementById('result');
var mouseOverCallback = function () {
    res.innerHTML = 'enter';
}

var mouseOutCallback = function () {
    res.innerHTML = 'leave';
}

span.parentNode.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOverCallback);
span.parentNode.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOutCallback);
```

This seems to work fine in achieving the functionality you want in Firefox too. However, if you mean that you are *not allowed* to change the button for whatever reason, then this probably won't be applicable.

Also, be aware that:

- The events were changed from `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to `mouseover` and `mouseout` respectively because according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave), the first two are fired for each element in the hierarchy while the last two fire only once
- The style `pointer-events: none` was added to the span so it doesn't process mouse events itself (when I tested on Chrome without this styling, moving over the span was firing a `mouseout` on the button and then another `mouseover`, which is probably undesirable)